# Collapse/Expand Images

Tags: asp.net, ajax, graphics

Ok so this is super basic. I just got done implementing the collapsible panel using the MS AJAX Toolkit and was wondering if anyone knew where to get the collapse and expand images that they use in their [demo](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/CollapsiblePanel/CollapsiblePanel.aspx)?

One would think these images would be distributed with the toolkit...if so - where are they found? Any recommendations for collapse/expand images in open-source-creative-commons domain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can set them using the properties

```
ExpandedImage="~/images/collapse.jpg"
CollapsedImage="~/images/expand.jpg"
```

the images can be found inside the toolkit

if you want to add your custom image you can get them from http://www.iconfinder.net

Answer (score 0):

you can find them if you view the source code on the sample page... no they're not included, though. this is so you can provide your own images.

on a side note, have you tried implementing this functionality using jquery? :)